# CoreML + Mobilenet SSD v1 slow on my macbook air

Tags: ios, swift, macos, coreml

I'm new to Core ML, been toying with it starting today. I tried to use a machine learning model called MobileNet SSD in real-time. It works, but it's rather slow. I see people talking about 20-30fps at the least, my MacBook gets to maybe three at max. Not sure where to start looking for what I did wrong, though.

I based my project on `https://github.com/vonholst/SSDMobileNet_CoreML` (which is for iOS, I translated it to macOS). If I run that with the simulator it's slow there, too.

I also tried using that GitHub project with the iPhone simulator by feeding it the same image over and over again (rather than sampling from the camera), and it still gets stuck at about the same frame rate.

What could cause this?

Comment: It is possible that Core ML on your Mac does not use the GPU. What sort of GPU does your MacBook Air have?

Comment: Hey Matthijs. I've got an Intel HD Graphics 6000 1536 MB. Using the `useCPUOnly` doesn't change the speed, so maybe. I'm not sure what to look for. Thanks for your work btw.

Comment: I don't know if there is a page somewhere that lists the Mac GPUs that Core ML works on. But if `usesCPUOnly` gives the same speed, it's not using the GPU on your Mac.